# Reset/destroy object instance

Tags: java, object, reset

I am translating PHP code to JAVA code.

PHP code snippet:

```
class Population {
        private $ind;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->ind = array();
        }

        function ResetObject() {
            foreach ($this as $key => $value) {
                unset($this->$key);
            }
        }
}

$temppop->ResetObject();
```

How to substitute `ResetObject` in JAVA code in order to delete `temppop` from memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to manually delete it from memory, Java has garbage collection to do this for you.

If you want you can call `System.gc()` to tell the JVM you want to do a garbage collection, but it can just ignore you till it's available to take the request.

Comment: It could, but it is the answer to his question.

Comment: calling `System.gc()` is almost always ill advised.

Comment: @bmorris591 he clearly says _but it can just ignore you till it's available to take the request._ :)

Answer (score 0):

Java uses a Garbage Collector, which scours the heap looking for disconnected objects and reclaiming their memory.  You cannot force GC, but I believe (at least in 1.2) you can recommend it.  To make an object available for GC, simply set all references to it to null.